# Active Directory PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials when change password on next login policy is active

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication, principalcontext

I am using the classes in *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement*  namespace to interact with Active Directory from my web application. To authenticate user credentials against Active Directory I use the following line of code.

```
bool authSucceeded=principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
```

where **principalContext** is the PrincipalContext instance. **authSucceeded** is true when a user is authenticated with the provided credentials. But this method fails when a *'change password on next login* policy is active. For those users, even if they are created with a password 'Abcd_10' is not authenticated.

Anyone have an idea how I can authenticate a user in this state so that I can redirect him to a change password screen? I have done code for all the other tasks. But only this thing is missing.

Simply I need to know the reason why the

```
principalContext.ValidateCredentials
```

method returned false like due to incorrect password/invalid username/user is deactivated OR my requirement(is he being authenticated for password change)

If any idea, please share..